# Nested if function? Need to have cells change if the contents of other cells change?

Tags: excel, variables, if-statement, nested, cells

Having a lot of trouble with this. I need to be able to alter this excel page so that when you type in a product name `A, B, or C` into the summary page, or the month, the actual and projected sales will automatically show up based on what you enter for product name and month.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying Nested `IFS` but the month cell `B2` is formatted weird and `=if(B2="Jan",10)`doesn't make `10` show up. If that makes sense.

Comment: What is the format for cell B2?

Answer (score 0):

I think syntax of if statement is not correct.

Correct syntax is:

```
=IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

Please check it and correct its syntax.