# How to automatically change cell values based on other cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, vba

Having a lot of trouble with this. I need to be able to alter this excel page so that when you type in a product name A, B, or C into the summary page, or the month, the actual and projected sales will automatically show up based on what you enter for product name and month.

[IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/sex3wj.png[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/20sdhqq.png[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/flc1n8.png[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/2460y6s.png[/IMG]

I'm trying Nested IFS but the month cell B2 is formatted weird and =if(B2="Jan",10)doesn't make 10 show up. If that makes sense.

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: Basically I need to be able to format the cells on a "Summary tab". I need the actual and predicted sales cells to change automatically when you type in either "A", "B", or "C" in the product name cell or "January", "February", etc. for the month cell. The values for the actual and predicted cells are in separate tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested if function? Need to have cells change if the contents of other cells change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440231/nested-if-function-need-to-have-cells-change-if-the-contents-of-other-cells-cha)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **HLOOKUP** to return the value based on the month and product.

E.g. Channel1 Actual would be -

`=HLOOKUP(<month>,<sheetname>!<lookupRange>,<rowOffset>,0)`

So, for 'Channel1, Actual' you could type `=HLOOKUP($B$2,A!$C$5:$N$6,2,0)`

Since  will change based on the selected product (cell $B$1) you would need to create the lookupRange inside a **INDIRECT** function and specify the name of the sheet based on the Product field. This takes the text string that you create and converts it to an address.

`INDIRECT($B$1 & "!$C$5:$N$6)`

So our formula is now

`=HLOOKUP($B$2,INDIRECT($B$1 & "!$C$5:$N$6),2,0)`

This will only be useful for Channel 1 because the rowOffset = 2 (2nd row of the lookupRange, row 6). If we expand our lookupRange to cover the whole source table ($C$5:$N$9) we can re-use it for all Channels, as the result will be determined by rowOffset as long as rowOffset is less than or equal to the number of rows in the range.

However, a different rowOffset is required for each Channel, so we need to change the rowOffset based on the row it is on.
Since you only have 4 rows it is probably easier to do this manually.

E.g.

`=HLOOKUP($B$2,INDIRECT($B$1 & "!$C$5:$N$9),2,0)` - Channel1 Actual

`=HLOOKUP($B$2,INDIRECT($B$1 & "!$C$5:$N$9),3,0)` - Channel2 Actual

`=HLOOKUP($B$2,INDIRECT($B$1 & "!$C$5:$N$9),4,0)` - Channel3 Actual etc

Now you have formulas for Actual, you can repeat the process for Projected. Just change the lookupRange to match the Projected values table range including the headings ($C$15:$C$19) and make sure your rowOffet is correct for each row.

The other formulas in the summary are based on the numbers returned by the HLOOKUP.

I'm no expert but I think this should work. I hope it helps.